# How to access to Multiple $_FILES items?

Tags: php, html, upload

I have a program that let it's user to upload more than one image:

My HTML FORM:

```
<input type="file" name="image[]"/>
```

I add more items by JavaScript and user can upload more than one email by clicking on a button.

I have a PHP Function for uploading an Image, I want to send that array ($_FILES) to my upload function one by one, **I want to do something like these:**

```
 $_FILES['image'][][1]
```

OR

```
 $_FILES['image'][*][1]
```

By naming:

```
$_FILES['image']['name'][1]
```

This is working well but I named that item, I want to get all items something like  [] or [*]

I want to do this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['image']['name']),$i++){
    upload($_FILES['image'][*][$i])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure all filenames are being uploaded to the forms action php file by using `print_r($_FILES);`

Then use foreach, eg

`foreach ($_FILES as $key=> $info)
{
 print_r($info);
}`.